# line-based when sending a JSON through an ajax call

Tags: json, node.js, jquery

I need to perform an AJAX call to send some JSON object to a server

```
  $.ajax({
    url: serviceURL+'stores/'+store_id+'/karaoke/song/new',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { song: id, date: "date", user: "test", help: false, partners: [], likes: 0 },
    dataType: "json"
  });
```

that's what i got, I used wireshark to log what i was sending and what i was sending was this

```
JavaScript Object Notation: application/json
Line-based text data: application/json
song=name&date=date&user="test"&help=false&partners=[]&likes=0
```

How could that call, with the specified dataType and contentType could transform a JSON into line based text data, how can i send the JSON object instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to convert the json to a string before it is sent. Once it reaches the server it will be parsed.

```
var song = { song: id, date: "date", user: "test", help: false, partners: [], likes: 0 }

var json = JSON.stringify(song)

$.ajax({
    url: serviceURL+'stores/'+store_id+'/karaoke/song/new',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: json,
    dataType: "json"
 });
```